# How do I add a background/highlight color to specific words in a Wordpress Chatroom plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, chatroom

**Outline-**
I am running a Wordpress v4 installation and have installed a chatroom plugin: https://github.com/wp-plugins/chat-room (full code below).

I want to be able to highlight specific words that appear in chat when a user posts a message. For example, every time a user posts a message with the word "Dog" in it, it would have background colour so that it can be highlighted to everyone.

As the HTML output from the plugin is plain HTML, the best solution I have found is the following working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/4ny8adpg/2/.

**The Problem-**
When using the script from the jsfiddle above on the page where the chatroom is placed, it seems that the script either cannot find the words or cannot replace them. I do not understand why, as the HTML that is output from the chatroom scripts is plain HTML (exactly as shown in the jsfiddle). It's also worth noting that the script *will* find and replace words that are written into the HTML source on the same page.

**The Code-**
Below is the PHP, Javascript and example HTML output for the chat-room plugin. I did not write this plugin and the original author offers very very limited support.

PHP:

```
Class Chatroom {
    function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activation_hook' ) );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'deactivation_hook' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'maybe_create_chatroom_log_file' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'define_javascript_variables' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_updates', array( $this, 'ajax_check_updates_handler' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', array( $this, 'ajax_send_message_handler' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content_filter' ) );
    }
    function activation_hook() {
        $this->register_post_types();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    function deactivation_hook() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    function register_post_types() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Chat Rooms', 'post type general name', 'chatroom' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Chat Room', 'post type singular name', 'chatroom' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'chatroom' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found', 'chatroom' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found in Trash', 'chatroom' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __( 'Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' )
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title' )
        );
        register_post_type( 'chat-room', $args );
    }
    function enqueue_scripts() {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chat-room', plugins_url( 'chat-room.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chat-room-styles', plugins_url( 'chat-room.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
    function maybe_create_chatroom_log_file( $post_id, $post ) {
        if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return;
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $post->post_name . '-' . date( 'm-d-y', time() );
        if ( file_exists( $log_filename ) )
            return;
        wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' );
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
        fwrite( $handle, json_encode( array() ) );
        // TODO create warnings if the user can't create a file, and suggest putting FTP creds in wp-config
    }
    function define_javascript_variables() {
        global $post;
        if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return; ?>
        <script>
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
        var chatroom_slug = '<?echo $post->post_name; ?>';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    function ajax_check_updates_handler() {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
            if ( $message->id <= $_POST['last_update_id'] )
                unset( $messages[$key] );
        }
        $messages = array_values( $messages );
        echo json_encode( $messages );
        die;
    }
    /**
     * AJAX server-side handler for sending a message.
     *
     * Stores the message in a recent messages file.
     *
     * Clears out cache of any messages older than 10 seconds.
     */
    function ajax_send_message_handler() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $this->save_message( $_POST['chatroom_slug'], $current_user->id, $_POST['message'] );
        die;
    }
    function save_message( $chatroom_slug, $user_id, $content ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        if ( ! $user_text_color = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', true ) ) {
            // Set random color for each user
            $red = rand( 0, 16 );
            $green = 16 - $red;
            $blue = rand( 0, 16 );
            $user_text_color = '#' . dechex( $red^2 ) . dechex( $green^2 ) . dechex( $blue^2 );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', $user_text_color );
        }
        $content = esc_attr( $content );
        // Save the message in recent messages file
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        $last_message_id = 0; // Helps determine the new message's ID
        foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
            if ( time() - $message->time > 10 ) {
                $last_message_id = $message->id;
                unset( $messages[$key] );
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        $messages = array_values( $messages );
        if ( ! empty( $messages ) )
            $last_message_id = end( $messages )->id;
        $new_message_id = $last_message_id + 1;
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $new_message_id,
            'time' => time(),
            'sender' => $user_id,
            'contents' => $content,
            'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id . '"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
        );
        $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
        // Save the message in the daily log
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, date( 'm-d-y', time() ) );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $new_message_id,
            'time' => time(),
            'sender' => $user_id,
            'contents' => $content,
            'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id .'"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
        );
        $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
    }
    function write_log_file( $log_filename, $content ) {
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
        fwrite( $handle, $content );
    }
    function get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, $date = 'recent' ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $chatroom_slug . '-' . $date;
        return $log_filename;
    }
    function parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'r' );
        $contents = fread( $handle, filesize( $log_filename ) );
        fclose( $handle );
        return $contents;
    }
    function the_content_filter( $content ) {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return $content;
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )  {
            ?>You need to be logged in to participate in the chatroom.<?php
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="chat-container">
        </div>
        <textarea class="chat-text-entry"></textarea>
        <?php
        return '';
    }
}
$chatroom = new Chatroom();
```

Javascript:

```
var last_update_received = 0;
function chatroom_check_updates() {
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'check_updates',
            chatroom_slug: chatroom_slug,
            last_update_id: last_update_id
        },
        function (response) {
            chats = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
            if ( chats !== null ) {
                for ( i = 0; i < chats.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( jQuery('div.chat-container div.chat-message-'+chats[i].id).length )
                        continue;
                    jQuery('div.chat-container').html( jQuery('div.chat-container').html() + chatroom_strip_slashes(chats[i].html) );
                    last_update_id = chats[i].id;
                    jQuery('div.chat-container').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('div.chat-container')[0].scrollHeight - jQuery('div.chat-container').height() }, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    setTimeout( "chatroom_check_updates()", 1000 );
}

function chatroom_strip_slashes(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
        switch (n1) {
        case '\\':
            return '\\';
        case '0':
            return '\u0000';
        case '':
            return '';
        default:
            return n1;
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    last_update_id = 0;
    chatroom_check_updates();
    jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).keypress( function( event ) {
        if ( event.charCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 13 ) {
            chatroom_send_message();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function chatroom_send_message() {
    message = jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).val();
    jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).val('');
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'send_message',
            chatroom_slug: chatroom_slug,
            message: message
        },
        function (response) {
        }
    );

}
```

HTML Output:

```
<div class="chat-container">
    <div class="chat chat-message-111"><strong style="color: #840;">User 1</strong>: What is your favourite animal?</div>
    <div class="chat chat-message-112"><strong style="color: #840;">User 2</strong>: I vote for #dog. </div>
     <div class="chat chat-message-113"><strong style="color: #840;">User 3</strong>: I have a #cat!</div>
        </div>
```

My question really is, am I missing something obvious? Any help towards a solution will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: To provide better explanation.

EDIT 2: Added script output as requested

Var. Chats in chatroom_check_updates() Output:

```
[{"id":129,"time":1428340673,"sender":1,"contents":"What is your favourite animal?","html":"<div class=\"chat chat-message-129\"><strong style=\"color: #840;\">User 1<\/strong>: What is your favourite animal?<\/div>"},
{"id":130,"time":1428351683,"sender":2,"contents":"I vote for #dog.","html":"<div class=\"chat chat-message-130\"><strong style=\"color: #840;\">User 2<\/strong>: I vote for #dog.<\/div>"},
{"id":131,"time":1428352376,"sender":3,"contents":"I have a #cat!","html":"<div class=\"chat chat-message-131\"><strong style=\"color: #840;\">User 3<\/strong>: I have a #cat!<\/div>"}]
```

Comment: I'm assuming that "function chatroom_send_message()" sends the message to a php script? Then "function chatroom_check_updates()" replaces all of the messages in the chat box with the updated messages?

Comment: I believe so but I did not make this plugin and as mentioned I have a fairly limited knowledge of Javascript/PHP.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the output of: var chats in chatroom_check_updates()

Comment: @Bioto I have edited and added the code that is stored in a file when a user sends a message. I am quite new to this, so I do apologise if I did not understand exactly what you asked me to do.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/97vv6yum/1/   -   Your going to have to do something like that. I would do all of the changes before there added to the chatbox. That way right from the beginning all of your changes are made and you don't have to run any extra scripts.

Comment: @Bioto Thank you so much for taking the time to write this! It is a really good solution. I understand what your code is doing, but after several hours of trying to work out how to implement this into the plugins script to produce the desired effect, I have failed. I am going to keep trying! But if there is any further help you can give me, it would be hugely appreciated!